# What is the Hong Kong Businessman shouting before he tries to jump out the window?

Tags: translation, ready-player-one-2018

At approximately 6:57 into the *Ready Player One* film, there is a humorous scene in which the avatar (looking like Jason Voorhees) of a "Hong Kong Businessman" played by [David Forman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm9718192/) is killed. After being killed in the OASIS, the Hong Kong Businessman takes off his VR vizor, shouts something in a non-English language, runs across the desks of his office, and tries to jump out the window before being tackled by somebody else in his office.

It can be seen at about 3:36 in the following clip.

On Amazon Video, the subtitles just state "[SHOUTING IN JAPANESE]" (which really doesn't make much sense considering the name of the character is "Hong Kong Businessman").

**What is the translation of what the Hong Kong Businessman is shouting before he tries to jump out the window?**

I have tried Googling several things, I've also tried looking up the [movie script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=ready-player-one), but to no avail. Unfortunately, I'm just not seeing any answers to this question.

Comment: I've neither seen the movie or read the book, but from my experience, you might want to look at this scene on Youtube (if there's a clip), and scroll down the comments until some random user asks "What's he saying?", then do a cross-related check with trustworthy(er) sources. Youtube comments are a blight most of the time, but sometimes, they help... :)

Comment: If it isn't translated in the subtitles then it probably isn't important. In olden days actors were sometimes just told to make up something in their own language, occasionally with hilarious results.

Comment: Thanks @Jenayah. I've tried checking out Youtube clips but, unfortunately, I haven't found anything yet. I would have linked to it otherwise. Please add comment/edit if you find a suitable Youtube video of the comment.

Comment: @DJClayworth olden days, maybe, but this movie is less than two years old, and the "Since you speak _[insert non-English language here]_, say something that sounds very typical in that language" days are a bit frowned upon as of now.

Comment: On a side note, @entpnerd, you might get more results by asking on [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) (if it is indeed Japanese).

Comment: I just re-watched it, and it sounds like absolute gibberish. @Jenayah, why do you think speaking random gibberish in your own language would be frowned upon? I'm unsure to the logic of that. Why would that be an issue?

Comment: @Edlothiad the way I see it, it could be interpreted as placing the moneymoneymoney before the actual meaning, by favorizing "the general cliché of what a Japanese/South American/whatever non-English would sound like" over respect towards said language. IMO. (for what it's worth though, it _could_ be gibberish, I don't understand that language whatsoever so can't judge :p )

Comment: "Although it's successfully taught me Japanese I can't take these Duolingo notifications any more, AAAAAARGH!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to contact David Forman ("Hong Kong Businessman") himself:

> [image: screenshot of an e-mail by David Forman, transcribed below]
>   <sup><sub>*(Click thumbnail for full image)*</sub></sup>
>
> Hello [name obscured]
>
> I recall I was taught Mandarin on the day of the shoot but maybe they have dubbed me and are using a language of their own liking
>
> Sorry I cannot help
>
> Regards David Forman

I showed this to several people fluent in Mandarin and they were unable to comprehend what he said, so it looks like this was overdubbed.

Comment: Now the question is... what was he dubbed with... :-P

Comment: Damn over and above. Well done!

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the extras of the Blu-ray, it shows what the actor actually said. Phonetically:

> Guan le than me dou guan le.

Means

> “close, close, close them all down”.

Translated by a native speaker that is not me, but is absolutely trusted.

Comment: What language is he speaking?

Comment: Chinese @entpnerd

Comment: Mandarin or Canto?